Why do images invert to create a perfect image (ie a pinhole camera)
This image has always confused me, and it seems to be the go to example when explaining why images are inverted when looking through a pinhole camera.

I understand that light travels in a straight line. Thus, light from the top of the object after passing through the pinhole reaches the bottom of the camera screen and light from the bottom of the object passing through the pinhole reaches the top of the screen. What that doesn't explain is why the image is inverted. Intuitively to me, this explains the top of the image would be at the bottom and the bottom the top, but how does that invert them? To go a bit further, why don't we see some weird image like below?

Here, the top is the bottom, and the bottom is the top, but nothing is flipped. This makes more sense than as to why the image is randomly inverted. Furthermore, these examples always only take the top and bottom of the image being flipped. What about the rest of the image? In this example, the whole tree is reflecting light, not just the top and bottom. Following the pattern of lines, this seems to make less sense.

I added the blue lines as this would have to be the way the light "rays" travel in order to produce this image. Do the light rays actually cross over each other? And again, why is the image built perfectly inverted, instead of some weird upright image built upside down?
I am assuming I am missing a fundamental part of undertesting light and rays, but every single example I come across breaks it down no more than: top of image now at bottom and bottom now at top. Not explaining why it is inverted, and how are the other rays of light traveling that make up the rest of whatever image is being flipped.


Do the light rays actually cross over each other?

Yes.   That's exactly what the pinhole does.   Since every light ray to come into the box passes through the hole, and since the hole is small, all the rays must cross at that one point.

how are the other rays of light traveling that make up the rest of whatever image is being flipped.

I love your image with the additional lines.  You should just use that.   Take every piece of your scene and draw a straight line from it through the pinhole onto the back wall.   Besides needing to invert the entire tree, you'll find that it inverts every subpart just as well.
Get rid of the tree and just draw the stump.   The line from the top of the stump, through the pinhole, and onto the wall will strike below the line that starts at the bottom of the stump.
Because every line must cross at the pinhole, that reverses the image (both vertically and horizontally).


Furthermore, these examples always only take the top and bottom of the image being flipped. What about the rest of the image?

It's the same reason why it seems like mirrors only flip horizontally and not vertically. If you look at the "back" of your image, yes, there is horizontal flipping also. But typically we are not looking at the "back" of the image. We are looking at it being projected onto something that we have flipped horizontally in order to look at the "front" of the image.

It might be easier to visualize if instead of a tree you have a few numbered dots in a vertical line and trace the rays: you will easily see that they are in reverse order in the formed image. Imagine that instead of light it is a stick that pivots on the hole, as you move one end of the stick from the top of the tree to the bottom, the other end of the stick will move continuously in the opposite direction, it will never reverse direction.
